# Can't boot Arch on a Dell Vostro

Tags: windows-10, boot, usb, arch-linux, dell-vostro

I have bought a Dell Vostro 5590 equipped with Win 10, and I'd like to install Archlinux too, in dual boot with Win 10.

Unfortunately I cannot even start a live Arch: after entering the One-Time Boot Menu by pressing F12 during a reboot, as soon as I try to boot from the flash drive, a deafening BEEEEEP is followed by a System Scan, just like the laptop thinks something is going terribly wrong.

I can interrupt the scan, as everything is fine (the laptop was delivered to me a few hours ago), but everytime I try booting from the live arch the above behavior happens.

I have also tried another USB medium, but the result is the same.

On the other hand, a live Ubuntu flashed on the same USB medium starts just fine.

Any ideas? Should I simply call Dell and ask for support on this (which I don't think they will provide...)

Comment: In the bios there is a setting called safe boot, turn it off and try again.

Comment: In the BIOS Setup, under _Secure Boot_ there's an ON/OFF option named _Enable Secure Boot_, and another option, _Secure Boot Mode_ where I can choose either _Deployed Mode_ or _Audit Mode_. Do you have any suggestion on this? By the way [this](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=249303) seems to be on the same topic, and there the OP seems to have chosen to set off the first option I described above.

Comment: Since Ubuntu runs I doubt Dell will support you. Run Arch in a Virtual Machine. That is normally a better approach anyway.

Comment: Oh sorry, it is secure boot, turn it off (which may be called audit), see if Arch loads now.

Comment: @Moab, your suggestion worked even though other issues prevent me from installing Arch (or even Ubuntu!), for now. I have posted [another question](https://superuser.com/questions/1568111/change-to-hkey-local-machine-system-currentcontrolset-services-iastorv-does-not), but feel free to convert your comment in an answer, and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turn secure boot off in the bios.