# Change to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\iaStorV\ does not survive reboot

Tags: windows-10, ssd, windows-registry, ahci, dell-vostro

**Bottom line on top**

It seems that any changes to `0`'s *Data* column value in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\iaStorV\StartOverride` or `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\storahci\StartOverride` do not survive Windows 10 reboot. How do I make them do survive?

**Why do I need this?**

In an attempt to install Arch or Ubuntu beside the factory-installed Windows 10, in both cases I have hit the problem of Intel RST

Specifically, the live Arch does not see the SSD if I enter `fdisk -l`, whereas Ubuntu's install process tells me something along the lines "you cannot have RST".

**What I've tried so far**

Therefore I surfed the web and find out that the solution seems to be switching to AHCI, so I tried setting that from the UEFI BIOS of my Dell Vostro 5590; upon doing so, unfortunately, not even Windows 10 boots, but it bothers me with the hateful smiley-BSOD with an `INACCESSIBLE_BOOT_DEVICE` error.

So I came across [this](https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/ubuntu-installation-on-computers-with-intel-r-rst-enabled/15347), which clearly states that the aforementioned change in the BIOS should be done ***after*** changing the Registry.

However, it turns out that those changes do not survive a reboot, therefore I still get the hateful BSOD upon changing to AHCI in the BIOS.

Any suggestion on how to proceed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your problems with booting Windows in AHCI mode, try this procedure:

- Go back to IDE mode and restart Windows
- Launch the Command prompt as Administrator
- Type the following in the command prompt and press Enter:

  ```
    bcdedit /set {current} safeboot minimal
  ```
- After getting a message of operation successful, restart the computer
- In the BIOS enable AHCI and save the settings
- The computer will boot in safe mode and install all necessary drivers
- Launch the Command prompt as Administrator again and execute:

  ```
    bcdedit /deletevalue {current} safeboot
  ```
- Restart the computer again.
  This time, Windows should boot with AHCI enabled and without any problems.